# Fallback for localstorage using modernizr

Tags: javascript, html

I am using localstorage for store data and it does not work will on IE7. So I am using modernizr for detecting its support to browser. But I want to add fallback on IE7. In IE7 case where can I find fallback function for localstorage for IE7. I mean what need to done when it falls into false condition.

```
if(Modernizr.localstorage) {
alert(0)
} else {
//function
}
```

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin: I have google about it. I just want to know Is there anything inside the modernizr for fallback in IE7

Comment: after a quick 15 second research, modernizr is a javascript library for detecting support. It has no other features http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/using-modernizr.html

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr doesn't actually shim anything, it just detects wether or not a feature is supported. You can combine it with [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com) to conditionally load the local-storage-js polyfill to fallback appropriately.